# PyUno and calc/spreadsheet: how to export single sheet to csv?

Tags: python, csv, spreadsheet, pyuno

I need to automate some spreadsheet manipulation and exporting via PyUNO, but I'm struggling on exporting a single sheet to CSV.

I made a simple shell script that first launch LibreOffice to open a given .xlsx file and then run a python3 script to execute all the needed logic.

Now I need to just export the current (`ActiveSheet`) to .csv but the PyUNO and OO UNO documentations are really terrible IMHO and I cannot find anything related to this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Below is a simplified version of my script

```py
import socket
import uno

def init():
    # get the uno component context from the PyUNO runtime
    localContext = uno.getComponentContext()

    # create the UnoUrlResolver
    resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
                "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )

    # connect to the running office
    ctx = resolver.resolve( "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" )
    smgr = ctx.ServiceManager

    # get the central desktop object
    desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)

    # access the current writer document
    model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

    return model

model = init()

active_sheet = model.CurrentController.ActiveSheet

# business logic

# now I need to export active_sheet to .csv
```

#### Bonus question

How can I get the opened file name with PyUNO?

Comment: `the PyUNO and OO UNO documentations are really terrible` — People say this about pretty well every technology. IMHO this simply means you need to take the time to become familiar with what's available (and it does take time initially). There is a lot of information about UNO out there if you know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [How to use python uno to open xls file and save as csv as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71889593/how-to-use-python-uno-to-open-xls-file-and-save-as-csv-as-utf-8). The command to **Export** is [storeToURL()](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1frame_1_1XStorable.html#af48930bc64a00251aa50915bf087f274) (while `storeAsURL()` is like *Save As*) and the command to get the currently saved filename is [getURL()](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1frame_1_1XModel.html#ae3c4fecf585029fd3c5432e277465346).

A search turned up [this code](https://gist.github.com/noirbizarre/229589f0e8489f282e30a81b6be6e48a) which I will reproduce in full since it seems to be what you're looking for.

```
import os
import unicodedata

from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue


def csv_properties():
    '''Build the dialog parameter for UTF-8 CSV'''
    props = []
    p = PropertyValue()
    p.Name = 'FilterName'
    p.Value = 'Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)'
    props.append(p)
    p = PropertyValue()
    p.Name = 'FilterOptions'
    p.Value = '59,34,76,1,,0,false,true,true,false'
    props.append(p)
    return tuple(props)


def export_sheets_to_csv():
    '''Iter over each sheet and save it as CSV file. '''
    desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()  # noqa
    model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
    controller = model.getCurrentController()
    dirname = os.path.dirname(model.URL)
    for sheet in model.Sheets:
        controller.setActiveSheet(sheet)
        name = sheet.getName().lower().replace(' ', '-')
        name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', name).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        filename = '{0}/{1}.csv'.format(dirname, name.decode('ascii'))
        model.storeToURL(filename, csv_properties())

g_exportedScripts = export_sheets_to_csv,
```